# Not able to retrieve array from cookie on page load

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angularjs-ng-repeat

Not sure of how correct is the title to my question ,
i am storing the input of the searches in an array and placing that array in a cookie . while the page refreshes i use init function to initialise the arr to be used in ng repeat with the one stored in the cookie . but i am facing error :

```
nameapp.controller('NameCtrl',
        function($scope,$http,$window, $cookieStore,$sessionStorage,$cookies ,myService){
    // code for storing array in the cookie 

              $http.get('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=w&q='+$scope.stock).success(function(data,status)
            {
               $scope.share=JSON.parse(data.substring(5,data.length-2));
                $scope.arr.push($scope.share);----> error here 
                console.log(status+"-------"+JSON.stringify($scope.arr));
            }).error( function ()
        {
        alert("fail");
        })
    }
        ;

$scope.init = function () {
    var s =$cookies.get("arr");
       $scope.arr=$cookies.get("arr") ;
    console.log("JSON.stringify($cookies.get('arr'))="+s);
}
    }
    );
    </script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="NameCtrl" ng-init="init()">

<form ng-submit="finddet()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="stock">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>

    <li ng-repeat="sr in arr track by $index"> value : {{sr.l_cur}} <a href='#' ng-click="removename(sr)"> remove </a></li> 
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

on the ---> line , error in console as :

```
TypeError: $scope.arr.push is not a function
    at (index):99
```

Not  sure how to initialise the ng repeat array with the one in the cookie on page load . Any correction please .

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is String and cant be another object. So transform your array to json before save and restore back to object on load